# PySpark specifying parquet file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code to process text file

```
textFile = sc.textFile(inputFile,numPart).map(mTorv,True)

db = textFile.
  flatMap(fmTocrv,True).
  reduceByKey(rbkGroupCols,numPart).
  mapValues(mvDodbs).
  filter(lambda (x,y): y is not None).
  persist()
```

How can i do the same for parquet files?

Comment: It will also work for Parquet data once you load it into an RDD. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: I meant what is the syntax for doing the same for the parquet file

Comment: `sqlContext.read.parquet` and then you can convert the Data Frame to an RDD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlContext.read.parquet` (to load Parquet data into a Data Frame) and then convert the DF to an RDD with `rdd.df`.